# NSArray Memory Address

Tags: objective-c, nsarray

Here's my test code

```
NSArray *arr = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"1", @"2", nil];
NSLog(@"arr:    %p", arr);
NSLog(@"arr[0]: %p", arr[0]);
NSLog(@"arr[1]: %p", arr[1]);
```

In my opinion, arr and arr[0] should have the same address
Just like this

```
int iarr[2] = {2, 5};
printf("iarr:    %p\n", iarr);
printf("iarr[0]: %p", &iarr[0]);

iarr:    0xbfffdbec
iarr[0]: 0xbfffdbec
```

but why I Log address using %p, it show something like follow

```
2013-07-16 12:51:35.472 TEST[6766:14003] arr:    0x8422f70
2013-07-16 12:51:35.473 TEST[6766:14003] arr[0]: 0x8a5e0
2013-07-16 12:51:35.473 TEST[6766:14003] arr[1]: 0x8a5f0
```

Why arr and arr[0] have different address?

Comment: Why is this question being downvoted? It's clear. It contains code demonstrating the issue being asked.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`arr` is the address of the `NSArray` object.

`arr[0]` is really a call to `[arr objectAtIndex:0]` meaning that `arr[0]` is the address of the first object in the array.

Unlike a basic C-array, an `NSArray` object will be at a completely different memory address than any of the objects that happen to be in the array.

Answer (score 1):

Since the **object stored in the `NSArray` object is also an object** unlike C-array where we store values in array, So in objective C, every object will be at totally different location.